# How to re-order colander fields in a form?

Tags: python, deform, colander, kotti

I used form inheritance to create a new form, for instance:

```
class MyForm(ParentForm):
    employment_date = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.Date(),
        title=_(u'Employment Date')
    )
```

Lets say the order of the ***ParentForm*** fields is

- name
- email
- biography

I want the new field, ***employment_date*** to be inserted after the email field, i.e.

- name
- email
- employment_date
- biography

I want to achieve this without redefining the fields in my schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `insert_before` argument when adding your schemaNode object (you'll have to reference 'biography' as there is no `insert_after` argument to use with email):

```
class MyForm(ParentForm):
    employment_date = colander.SchemaNode(
        colander.Date(),
        title=_(u'Employment Date'),
        insert_before='biography',
    )
```

[Colander schemaNode docs](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/basics.html)